# how to enable and disable php7 modules in linux server 16.4

Tags: 16.04, php7

I have mad a custom ini files in `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available`. how can I enable it. I have tried `php5enmod, and php7enmod`. none worked for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use the command `phpenmod`.

Comment: It would be more help if you provided details on how to explicitly use this command.

Comment: My "phpenmod" is pointing to php5.6 when I'm running: sudo phpenmod oci8 ===>
WARNING: Module oci8 ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available

Comment: OFFICIAL MANUAL TOLD ME:    `usage: phpenmod [ -v ALL|php_version ] [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name [ module_name_2 ]`   so i run `phpenmod -v 7.1 -s apache2 soap`   version and SAPI you can know from **/usr/lib/php/**

Answer (score 4):

- `phpenmod moduleName` enables a module to php7 (restart apache after that `sudo service apache2 restart`)
- `phpdismod moduleName` disables a module to php7 (restart apache after that `sudo service apache2 restart`)
- `php -m` lists the loaded modules

Answer (score 3):

If you have several php versions intalled you can also use this syntax:

```
phpenmod -v 5.6 <modulename>
phpenmod -v 7.1 <modulename>
...
```

That worked in my case because I have 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 installed, but because of requirements I have to run my apache2 with 7.2.

Comment: Thanks, lifesaver!

Comment: Glad I could help! It saved my life too when I learnt it :D

Answer (score 1):

- To check available modules, run `php -m` - it's a content of `/etc/php/yourPHPVersion/mods-available`
- Select module from the list and enable it (let's say you want to enable soap) `phpenmod soap`
- Reload apache2 `service apache2 reload` or `systemctl reload apache2`
  And you have a module enabled.
- To disable the same module, run `phpdismod soap`, reload apache2 `service apache2 reload`